# ReSharper ignore certain folder(s) on TODO explorer

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, resharper

I use SignalR in my solution, their Nuget package brings in java scripts. It's OK, but problem is - there is TODO's in there which now shows up under my TODO list.

So, I'd like to ignore specific folder(s) or file(s) when ReSharper scan's for TODO's

I tried to exclude folder from "Code Inspections" but that doesn't seem to apply to TODO's.

Possible? (latest resharper, vs2015)

Comment: 8 months later and still nothing

Comment: I did post answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ReSharper -> Options

Under `Code Inspection/Generated Code` add folder/files to be excluded and TODO's from there won't be on a list.

Comment: Am I missing something? Is there a way to set up a general path/pattern so I dont have to do it for each project? So instead of <ProjectA>/wwwroot/vendor, I can do something like **/wwwroot/vendor. That would be great.

Comment: This does not work for me with VS2017. It ignores the code, but still adds TODO comments to the todo list.