# Instruct Resharper to ignore folders for C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, resharper

I'm using Resharper 2018.3.1 and Entity Framework Core. The remaining Resharper warnings are from my `Migrations` directory where most of this code is code-generated. I've tried disabling the solution-wide analysis for this directory, yet I still get warnings for the code generated files. Is there some magic sauce I'm missing? I am also using a custom EF Core `CSharpHelper`, is there a way to annotate the code files using that facility?

Comment: [ReSharper | Options | Code Inspection | Generated Code](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Reference__Options__Code_Inspection__Generated_Code.html)

Comment: @RobertHarvey yea - for some reason the ef core generators don't put .designer.cs on there.

Comment: What are the files called?  That dialog allows you to specify more options than just `.designer.cs`.

Comment: `20190103144925_InitialCreate.cs` (a timestamp and a name; there's one called `.designer` too) & `MyDbContextModelSnapshot.cs` - nothing too regular to hold on to.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39794752 -- That dialog doesn't allow you to exclude folders?

Comment: yea i hate doing that per file. i like things to be automagic. i might have found the code generator for the files themselves, going to try it out. might open a PR for ef core to include this comment in the file...

Comment: Better to use Resharper ignore attribution, I would think.

Comment: @RobertHarvey yea but this is an assembly that may not reference anything that has those annotations. `"// ReSharper disable All"` is what i'm aiming for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to override the `CSharpMigrationsGenerator`'s `GenerateMigration`, `GenerateMetadata` and `GenerateSnapshot` methods and place the `// ReSharper disable All` comment at the start of all of the files.